# Layered Navigation not displaying

Tags: magento-1.7, layered-navigation, css

The layered navigation on my current project is not displaying on the catalog pages. It is configured in the admin panel, but i am afraid some css may be wrong causing it not to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate / add the price slider html.

The JavaScript code from `js/amasty/amshopby/amshopby.js` line 106
`slider.up('dd').previous('dt').observe('click', function() {` stops on .previous() method call.

Apparently `slider.up('dd')` doesn't return any object, which means that some needed html hasn't been loaded.

Please check your amasty shopby module settings, or restore any edited files